# Inverses of elements for (Part One) an ideal generated by a reducible polynomial and (Part Two) an irreducible polynomial with no real roots

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modular-arithmetic, ideals, maximal-and-prime-ideals

Let $\langle x^2-4 \rangle$ denote the ideal generated by the polynomial $x^2-4$. (Artin uses $(x^2-4)$.)

In connection with this [Visualizing quotient polynomial rings are fields for maximal ideals which are generated by irreducible monic](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3006167/visualizing-quotient-polynomial-rings-are-fields-for-maximal-ideals-which-are-ge)

Part One: Inverses in the quotient ring $\mathbb R[x]/\langle x^2-4 \rangle$.

1. Consider the quotient ring $\mathbb R[x]/\langle x^2-4 \rangle$ and one of its elements $\overline {x^2-2x} = [x^2+2x+\langle x^2-4 \rangle]$. I think this element has no multiplicative inverse because $x^2-2x=0$ for $x=2$. **Is that correct?**
2. In the quotient ring, $\mathbb R[x]/\langle x-2 \rangle$, the relation is "x=2". This relation is used to compute inverses. **What exactly is the relation in the quotient ring $\mathbb R[x]/\langle x^2-4 \rangle$?** I think it is "$x=2$ or $x=-2$".
3. **In the quotient ring $\mathbb R[x]/\langle x^2-4 \rangle$, does the element $\overline {x+1} = [x+1+\langle x^2-4 \rangle]$ have an inverse, and why? If so, then what is it?** (I think I can answer these if I know the answer for 2.)

Part Two: Inverses in the quotient ring $\mathbb R[x]/\langle x^2+1 \rangle$.

For the quotient ring $\mathbb R[x]/\langle x-2 \rangle$, the relation is $x=2$ so inverse of $\overline p = [p(x)+\langle x-2 \rangle]$ is $\overline {\frac{1}{p(2)}}$.

For the quotient ring $\mathbb R[x]/\langle x^2+1 \rangle$, I believe $x^2+1$ is irreducible in $\mathbb R[x]$, so $\mathbb R[x]/\langle x^2+1 \rangle$ is a field.

To compute the inverse of $\overline p = [p(x)+\langle x^2+1 \rangle]$, I believe I need the relation in the quotient ring $\mathbb R[x]/\langle x^2+1 \rangle$.

1. **What's the relation in the quotient ring $\mathbb R[x]/\langle x^2+1 \rangle$?** I think it is "$x= i$ or $x=-i$".
2. What is the inverse of $\overline p = [p(x)+\langle x^2+1 \rangle]$?

( I think I will know the answer if I know the answer to 2 in Part One.)

Comment: Generally a post should have one clearly outlined question. It's not even clear what the questions are here.

Comment: $(x+1)(ax+b)=ad+(a+b)x+a(x^2+b/a-d)=1+c(x^2-4)$. $a=-b$, $d=3$, $a=1/3$. Inverse is $(x-1)/3$. Check, we get $x^2/3-1/3=(x^2-4)/3+1$.

Comment: @MattSamuel Thank you! 1. What is the multiplicative inverse for $\overline {x^2-2x}$? 2. What is the relation in for the quotient ring $\mathbb R[x]/\langle x^2-4 \rangle$ ? 3. I will try to analyze your inverse for $x+1$ tomorrow. 4. I think to get inverses, we need to come up with a relation. What's the relation for the quotient ring $\mathbb R[x]/\langle x^2+1 \rangle$?

Comment: @MattSamuel I edited to hopefully clarify.

Comment: $x^2-2x=x(x-2)$ is a zero divisor. No inverse.

Comment: @MattSamuel Part One: So what exactly is the relation? "$x=2$ or $x=-2$"? Part Two:  what about $x^2+1$?

Comment: You can't get this ring by substituting a real number, so it's neither $2$ nor $-2$. We have $(x-2)(x+2)=0$, and there's no real number satisfying this.

Comment: For the quotient by $(x^2+1)$, note that $x^2=-1$. Again there's no real number satisfying this, but there is a complex number satisfying it.

Comment: @MattSamuel 1. What's the difference between "$(x-2)(x+2)=0$" and "$x=2$ or $x=-2$" ? 2. So what's the inverse for example of $\overline{x+1}$ in the quotient by $\langle x^2+1 \rangle$ ?

Comment: The difference is that $x$ is simply not a real number. $x-2$ and $x+2$ are not zero, but their product is.